# Child component holding on to old prop value despite being passed an updated one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component called Plot.js. This takes a prop `testParam`. Parent component looks like this:

```
....
this.state = {
   testParam: "some value",
};

...
return (
  <Plot
    testParam={props.testParam}
  />
);
```

And Plot is:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Plot(props) {
  console.log("props.testParam is ", props.testParam);

  const [localTestParam, setLocalTestParam] = useState(props.testParam);

  useEffect(() => {
      console.log("in useEffect, localTestParam is now ", localTestParam);

  }, [props.testParam]);
  ...
}
```

Now I run the app and I see as expected:

```
props.testParam is  some value
in useEffect, localTestParam is now  some value
```

Now the user gives an input and Plot sends it up to the parent component, which changes the `testParam` by updating its state:

```
this.setState({
  testParam: "A completely different value"
});
```

By doing so, the child Plot components re-render, and in the logs I see:

```
props.testParam is  A completely different value
in useEffect, localTestParam is now  some value
```

So somehow, the old value is getting help in the `localTestParam` property even though the component has re-rendered and the value has changed. Whats going on?

**EDIT**

Im going to add a bit more context to this question to show the reason Im using state in the child component.

Each child Plot component each get a polygon (an array of points). This is passed to them by the parent component. There are 3 types of polygons - when 1 type is changed, it should change in all Plot components showing that polygon type. Users change a polygon by interacting with HTML Canvas and dragging a point - as they drag (on mouse down) I redraw that component only and I do this by updating its state with a local copy of the polygon, which changes as a user drags the point. When the user stops dragging (and on mouse up), now that change is confirmed, and its propagated back up to the parent, which updates its state and re-renders everything.

So I need to use a local state in the Plot component but also get the new update state when the parent component updates its state and re-render all the Plots. But from what Im learning here, `useEffect` is not the correct hook to use when the child components re-render...

**EDIT**

I have tried the answer by @AKX below, but have run into more problems. I'll go into more details: each Plot component receives a "plot" object with an array of polygon points, as well as some other properties like name of plot.

```
function Plot(props) {

  const [localPlot, setLocalPlot] = useState(props.plot);
  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.plotIndex + " in useEffect, props is now ", props.plot);

    // here we get the Canvas context and draw to it, including drawing the polygon


  }, [localPlot]);

  return (
    <>
        <canvas
          style={{ border: "thick solid #32a1ce" }}
          className="canvas"
          id={`canvas-${props.plotIndex}`}
          width={localPlot.width}
          height={localPlot.height}
          onMouseDown={(e) => {
            let nativeEvent = e.nativeEvent;
            handleMouseDown(nativeEvent);
          }}
          onMouseMove={(e) => {
            let nativeEvent = e.nativeEvent;
            handleMouseMove(nativeEvent);
          }}
          onMouseUp={(e) => {
            let nativeEvent = e.nativeEvent;
            handleMouseUp(nativeEvent);
          }}
        />
  );
```

As the user drags the polygon, I need to keep re-drawing the Plot component to show the new placement of the polygon. I do this by changing the points in localPlot.points in onMouseMove:

```
  const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
    
     let newPointsCanvas = [event.offsetX, event.offsetY];

      // calculate the new points here and set as localPlot.points

        setLocalPlot(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localPlot)));
      }
    }
  };
```

And in `handleMouseUp` I propagate back up to parent component as now the points change is permanent:

```
const handleMouseUp = (event) => {
    isMouseDown = false;

    let change = {
      points: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localPlot.gate.points)),
    };

    //propagating up new points to parent component
    props.onEditPoints(change);
  } 
};
```

This works well, the polygon drags as the user moves the mouse, but when they let go and the parent component re-renders all the child Plot components, localPlot still has the old points. So I did as @AKX suggested and add the line to `useEffect()`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setLocalPlot(props.plot);
```

This does indeed fix the issue - localPlot now has the correct points passed down from the parent, but it creates a new problem. As the user drags the polygon (and `setLocalPlot(props.plot)` is called within `handleMouseMove`), the polygon moves much faster than the user is dragging. It seems as if this is causing a loop effect - `setLocalPlot()` in `handleMouseMove()` reloads (I dont know if thats the right word but when I put a `console.log()` under `function Plot{` I can see it outputting as I drag the polygon) the component, and then the `setLocalPlot()` in `useEffect()` seems to reload it again, so if I move the polygon 2 pixels, it gets moved 4 etc. At this point, Im not even sure if what Im doing is possible, and whether I need a completely new approach...

**EDIT**

I have created a Codepen, which replicates the problem: https://codepen.io/mark-kelly-the-looper/pen/bGYzZQR
You can see as you drag how it takes off. Also, the second child component does not redraw with the new polygon coordinates..

**EDIT**
Ok I've added a more complete example, showing polygon dragging - with instance re-rendering - and then everything being updated on mouse up. Its here: https://codepen.io/mark-kelly-the-looper/pen/bGYzZQR?editors=0011

Comment: Re your codepen, I made a similar SVG-based drag-and-drop thing earlier - maybe it might be an inspiration.. https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-rectangle-draggy-0hy278

Comment: Thats quite neat. I suppose the difference here is an input in a child components affects all the other child components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing strange going on.

```
const [localTestParam, setLocalTestParam] = useState(props.testParam);
```

assigns the value of `props.testParam` to the state atom *once* on component mount, not when the component updates ("re-renders").

> So I need to use a local state in the Plot component but also get the new update state when the parent component updates its state and re-render all the Plots.

`useEffect` is exactly the correct hook, you just need to use it.

```
function Component({someProp}) {
  const [localValue, setLocalValue] = React.useState(someProp);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Update local value when identity someProp changes (identity).
    setLocalValue(someProp);
  }, [someProp]);
}
```

Comment: What would I use to update value on re-render?

Comment: It seems like you could remove the state from the Plot component, and rely on the `props.testParam` and useEffect to handle the changes. With your original example the state is being managed in the parent component and the child component.

Comment: Exactly what @TheFlorinator said. You're "forking props to state" with this. If you want the child component to just react to prop changes, don't use state.

Comment: thanks, I have updated the question to give more context

Comment: @Mark see my edit! :)

Comment: Thanks, updated question, new problem unfortunately! A loop effect